# jQuery IU droppable - Prevent item from being dropped in specific area if another item was dropped in the same area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to prevent an item from being dropped in a specific area if another item was dropped in the same area.

Is there a way (probably by using the disable function) to do this with jQuery UI?

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Laurent514/GyEF3/

The following code is used to inform the user of the ID of the dropzone on which the item was dropped. What I need here is a function that will prevent the user to drop item 2 on position 1 if item 1 was already dropped on position 1. Any ideas? I need a sort of prevent collision thing if an area is already "occupied" by an item.

```
 $( ".item" ).draggable({
   snap: ".dropzone",
   stop: function (event, ui) {
     var item = this;
     $('#dropzones li').each(function(){
         if($(item).position().left == $(this).position().left)
             alert($(this).attr('id'));
     });
   }
 });
```

Thanks!

Laurent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add droppable to your drop zone element. I also added revert to the draggable object.  You're position check will always pass regardless of whether an item was 'dropped' or not.  I used a combination of out and drop event to enable/disable a drop zone after something has been dropped.  This along with the use of revert will get you the desired result.  There are also ways to tailor the 'out-of-the-box' revert feature to satisfy your needs.

```
$(".dropzone").droppable({
    disabled: false,
    out: function ( event, ui ) {
        $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", false)
    },
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
         $(this).droppable("option", "disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyEF3/1/)

Comment: Strange! I put the code in a distant JS file and the console doesn't show the item position. Am I missing something?

Comment: What browser are you using?